# Can a rogue use Two Weapon Fighting to wield a shortsword and a pistol?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, homebrew, two-weapon-fighting

My game has renaissance firearms (Chapter 9: DMG, Firearms) and the rogue is proficient with a Pistol (1d10 piercing, 3lb, Ammunition (range 30/90), loading.

He has a custom feat that works similar to Crossbow Expert:

> Through a combination of smithing, tinkering and ingenuity, you've
>   discovered how to craft firearms.
>
> You gain proficiency with firearms. You can now ignore the loading
>   property of one-handed firearms. Being within 5 feet of a hostile
>   creature doesn’t impose disadvantage on your ranged attack rolls with
>   one-handed firearms.

He's also attempting to use Two-Weapon Fighting to wield a shortsword at the same time. (Chapter 9: PHB, Combat, Two-Weapon Fighting)

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon
>   that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack
>   with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other
>   hand. You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus
>   attack, unless that modifier is negative.
>
> If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon,
>   instead of making a melee attack with it.

From what I understand, he cannot dual wield a Renaissance Pistol and a Shortsword as 1) They aren't both *light*, and 2) They aren't both *melee*

My question is what should I do to follow the rules more closely, as well as help the rogue out? This style has become part of their character.

I found this for the Crossbow Expert Feat:

> When you use the Attack action and attack with a one-handed weapon,
>   you can use a bonus action to attack with a hand crossbow you are
>   holding.

**How do I modify this feat to get the two weapon pistol and sword style to fit better?**

The character concept is a swashbuckling sword and pistol rogue.  I feel that if I just added the above text, the feat would be overpowered.

---

Alternatives that I have looked into and that I don't really like (hence this question):

1. I am considering nerfing his pistol from 1d10 piercing to 1d8 piercing and giving it the *light* property so that he can dual wield it, even though it's not melee.
2. Ignore the fact that it's not melee;
3. Stick to RAW and tell him *too bad the game doesn't work that way*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### RAW? Not really; "Two-Weapon Fighting" is for melee weapons.

You provided the quote yourself, but I'll add the emphasis:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light **melee weapon** that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light **melee weapon** that you're holding in the other hand.

### Crossbow Expert vs. Your Feat

You've found the nearest equivalent to pistol-and-sword in RAW 5e.  You've built some of it into your custom feat, but you left out the part that would allow a pistol-and-sword style.

> When you use the Attack action and attack with a one-handed weapon, you can use a bonus action to attack with a hand crossbow (pistol) you are holding.

As a result, you *have* allowed the less-realistic of the two options.  Loading a black powder weapon is a long, complicated, multi-stage process; you have to load the powder, pack the ball, pack the wad, then load the primer. Typically, black powder pistoleros *carry more than one gun*.

#### How to solve your problem simply

1. Apply the bonus-action-shot rule from Crossbow Expert.
2. Have your *pistolerogue* carry more than one pistol.

   Instead of messing with Loading, adjust the custom feat to make drawing and holstering not require an action.  Characters with larger numbers of attacks or who expect to maintain fire for multiple rounds will have to purchase multiple weapons.  If pistols are suitably rare, that will serve as your balancing factor.

#### Experience base for this homebrew modification

I've done something similar for a pirate game in D&D 3.5, but the idea applies equally to D&D 5e.

Comment: Per pistol's *ammunition* property one still needs a free hand to reload, so dual-wielding without multiple pistols is out of the question entirely.

Comment: @AntiDrondert Which is what T.J.L. was saying.  Even if you *could* load them with a full hand (you can wield a shield with the Crossbow Feat and shoot twice, after all), there's still the issue of reload time, which is why his solution is to not deal with the loading/ammunition aspect in combat, and just have multiple single shot pistols.

Comment: Don't mean to cut in, but I was going to ask the same thing (with the hand crossbow.) Just to clarify, if I had a crossbow loaded and ready, having cast Ensnaring Strike on my last turn, and had to choose to either take a shot at a mage to break his concentration with the vines or defend against my attacker, I could use dual wield to do both?

Comment: @VictorB I'm not sure what you're asking... What does defending have to do with it?

Comment: @DanielZastoupil You cannot shoot a crossbow twice with a shield. Even with the Crossbow Expert feat, you still need a free hand to load a hand crossbow. A shield uses up the hand.

Comment: @t.j.l. thanks.  I found that out a few hours later after looking into it

Answer (score 1):

## The RAW doesn't allow for dual wielding.

It appears that you understand the rules as written, and exactly how you would be deviating from them.

## Alternative within RAW

You could allow the character to hold both weapons in such a way that one or the other could be used without having to drop the other.  In that way, they  can shoot or melee in a round.

## Alternative weapon

Modify the pistol in such a way that it can be used as a melee weapon. Perhaps add a blade to the front.  Modify the damage to 1d6 piercing ranged or melee.

### Reloading

Either way the character will not be able to reload the weapon without a free hand.